# Can anyone explain what the statement "parent = parent || document;" , not sure what it is trying to achieve?

Tags: javascript

The following **jewel.dom** module has a few functions for manipulating CSS classes. The module also exposes $() function, which is just a wrapper for the querySelectorAll() function. The $() function lets you use CSS selectors to easily select DOM elements, similar to the $() function in jQuery.

```
jewel.dom = (function() {
    function $(path, parent) {
        parent = parent || document;
        return parent.querySelectorAll(path);
    } 
    return { $: $};
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to optionally pass in a parent element from which the `querySelectorAll` should take place from. If no second parameter is provided, then the `querySelectorAll` is called from the document by default. For example:

```js
function $(path, parent) {
    parent = parent || document;
    return parent.querySelectorAll(path);
}

// Will return all divs in the document:
console.log($('div'));

const outer = document.querySelector('.outer');
// Will return all divs which are descendants of `.outer`:
console.log($('div', outer));
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that in ES6 this could be simplified with the use of default parameters:

```js
function $(path, parent=document) {
    return parent.querySelectorAll(path);
}

// Will return all divs in the document:
console.log($('div'));

const outer = document.querySelector('.outer');
// Will return all divs which are descendants of `.outer`:
console.log($('div', outer));
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `parent` is false-y `document` will be used instead.

It's equivalent to saying:

```
if(!parent) {
    parent = document;
}
```

Comment: Under what condition , the parent  is false?

Comment: @Jason if it is undefined. Undefined is considered `false-y`

Comment: @NickParsons, if i pass a parent object to the function $(), it will search the elements under the parent tree, if not, it will search the whole document tree for that element.